# Async & Tasks - Searching through a list of websites

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm trying to create a class that can search a string in a list of websites in an asynchronous way.

The following code is working, but I'm getting a feeling that it's done totally wrong:

```
 public static class Searcher
    {

        public struct SearchResult
        {
            public SearchResult(string Url, bool Found)
            {
                this.Url = Url;
                this.Found = Found;
            }             

            public string Url;
            public bool Found;
        }

        public async static Task<SearchResult> SearchWebsiteAsync(string url, string str)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Found string in website {0}", url);
            bool foundString = (urlContents.Contains(str) ? true : false);

            return new SearchResult(url, foundString);
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResult>> StartSearch(string str)
        {
            List<SearchResult> results = new List<SearchResult>();
            List<Task<SearchResult>> taskList = new List<Task<SearchResult>>();

            foreach (var url in TheWeb.URLs)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Searching URL {0}", url);

                var t = new Task<Task<SearchResult>>(() => SearchWebsiteAsync(url, str));
                t.Start();
                taskList.Add(t.Result);
            }
            //Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            foreach (var task in taskList) {
                results.Add(task.Result);
            }            

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Especially that I have `Task`'s inside `Task`'s : `var t = new Task<Task<SearchResult>>(() => SearchWebsiteAsync(url, str));`

Is there are a better way (if possible without `Parallel` because I'm still trying to get some understanding of async-await and tasks)

Comment: If the code is working then this is more suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, making this an off top question.

Comment: `HttpClient`s are designed to be reused and relatively long-lived; don't create a new one for each request.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand in your code, it doesn't really matter which task the search results come from (since the `url` is contained in your Search Results anyway).

So how about

```
public static async Task<SearchResult[]> StartSearch(string str)
{
    List<Task<SearchResult>> taskList = new List<Task<SearchResult>>();

    foreach (var url in TheWeb.URLs)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Searching URL {0}", url);
        taskList.Add(SearchWebsiteAsync(url, str));
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll<SearchResult>(taskList);
}
```

`async` functions return `Task` objects. You don't need to `new Task(() => {...})` to initialize them. Just calling an `async` function is enough to get a valid `Task` object back.

I am assuming here that you are OK with getting all the search results at the same time. If that assumption is incorrect do let me know. There are other solutions possible.